# Using Pyqt Print support but getting error "Object is not callable"

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am new to python and I am learning from different resources
I am trying to use PYQT5 print support but I am getting error, I try my best to solve this problem from google but i found no solution so I am asking this question here please 
below is my code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets ,QtPrintSupport

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(615, 356)
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 571, 301))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.frame)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 10, 331, 71))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.frame)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 521, 121))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 250, 91, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.print)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Column"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Print"))

    def print (self):
        dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog()
        if dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            self.frame().print_(dialog.printer())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and i am getting this error

```
File "print.py", line 74, in print
    self.frame().print_(dialog.printer())
TypeError: 'QFrame' object is not callable
```

please tell me the solution as I am new in python 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

- An object is not callable, so you should not use `()`, a class if it is.
- A QFrame does not have the `print_` method, only QTextEdit and some classes have it, in the general case you should use QPainter.
- The class that provides Qt Designer is not a widget so I recommend you not to modify it or implement the logic there since you will have several problems, it is best to create a class that inherits the appropriate widget according to the template and use the class of Qt Designer to fill it

Considering the above, the solution is as follows:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtPrintSupport

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(615, 356)
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 571, 301))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.frame)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 10, 331, 71))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.frame)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 521, 121))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 250, 91, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setText("Print")

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.print)

    def print(self):
        printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter()
        printer.setOutputFormat(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.PdfFormat)
        printer.setPageMargins(12, 16, 12, 20, QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.Millimeter)
        printer.setFullPage(False)
        dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog(printer, self)
        if dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(dialog.printer())
            xscale = printer.pageRect().width() /float(w.width())
            yscale = printer.pageRect().height() /float(w.height())
            scale = min(xscale, yscale)
            painter.translate(printer.paperRect().center())
            painter.scale(scale, scale)
            painter.translate(-w.width()/ 2, -w.height()/ 2)
            self.frame.render(painter)
            painter.end()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you eyllanesc for your support I tried your code and now I am getting this error

QPrintDialog: Cannot be used on non-native printers
QPrintDialog: Cannot be used on non-native printers

Comment: @SheerazAhmad What version of PyQt5 do you have? What is your OS ?, I recommend using a version of PyQt5 higher than 5.9

Comment: currently I am using 5.11.2 on Windows 10

Comment: @SheerazAhmad try commenting the line:`printer.setOutputFormat(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.PdfFormat)`